# public folder was lock while running node project

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

I am working on node 14.x version at ubuntu 18.04 os while running the project I tried to upload an object the root user locked the public folder after that I was unable to use the object that I uploaded. if I want to use that object I want to change the permission or else I want to remove all the objects on the public folder and have to try again.

Comment: Ask the Root or Administrator that belongs to the machine, and ask him for permission to do so - else please use `man chmod` and `man chown` Moreover, End-User question are not suitable for serverfault but can be asked on superuser

Comment: but it was have to do every time every when I was upload at public folder.